# jQuery not showing next drop down list according to condition

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, drop-down-menu

MY logic is to make a Library Management System in which it first asks for students Class Name, than if Intermediate is selected (which is 1 in database) then show Intermediate Groups else if BS is selected than show BS Department.

```
<?php 

require '/include/connect.inc.php';
require '/include/core.inc.php';

?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="include/JS/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="include/JS/jQuery.js"></script>
<style>tr.Department_Options{ display: none; }</style>
<div class="articles">
    <form method="POST" action="#">
        <table align="center">
<tr><th><label for="ChoosedClassID">Class : </label></th><td><select  name="ChoosedClassID" id="ChoosedClassID"><option  disabled selected>Select Class :</option><?php 
$query="SELECT ClassID,ClassName from class ORDER BY ClassName ASC";
$query_run=mysqli_query($connect,$query) OR die(mysqli_error($connect));
while($catch=mysqli_fetch_array($query_run)) {
    $ClassName=$catch['ClassName'];
    $ClassID=$catch['ClassID']; ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $ClassID;?>"><?php echo $ClassName; ?></option> 
 <?php } ?></select><br></td></tr>

<tr id="tr_A" class="Department_Options"><th><label for="id_A">Choose Your Group : </label></th><td><select  name="InterGroupID" id="InterGroupID"><option  disabled selected>Intermediate Group :</option><?php
$query="SELECT DID,DepartmentName from department WHERE ClassID=1 ORDER BY DepartmentName ASC";
$query_run=mysqli_query($connect,$query) OR die(mysqli_error($connect));
while($catch=mysqli_fetch_array($query_run)) {
    $DepartmentName=$catch['DepartmentName'];
    $DID=$catch['DID']; ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $DID;?>"><?php echo $DepartmentName; ?></option> 
 <?php } ?></select><br></td></tr>

<tr id="tr_B" class="Department_Options"><th><label for="id_B">Choose Department : </label></th><td><select  name="DepartmentName" id="DepartmentName"><option  disabled selected>BS Department Name</option><?php
$query="SELECT DID,DepartmentName from department WHERE ClassID=2 ORDER BY DepartmentName ASC";
$query_run=mysqli_query($connect,$query) OR die(mysqli_error($connect));
while($catch=mysqli_fetch_array($query_run)) {
    $DepartmentName=$catch['DepartmentName'];
    $DID=$catch['DID']; ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $DID;?>"><?php echo $DepartmentName; ?></option> 
 <?php } ?></select><br></td></tr>
</table>                  
</form>
</div>
```

The jQuery.js File

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#ChoosedClassID').on('change', function() {         

        $('tr.Department_Options').hide();
        $('#tr_' + $(this).val() ).show();

    });

});
```

According to code above, When I select BS,Intermediate, Next Drop Down Meny doesn't appear.

What I want is that drop down menu appear and when I select some value from it, it should ask for Student Library Number and then I want to make insert query.

Comment: You should post the relevant html instead of the php, that makes it easier to test and to see the values of your id's.

Comment: @halfer No it's not running :(

Comment: @jeroen I am noob in jQuery, I just copy and pasted code from http://jsfiddle.net/iknowkungfoo/TKamw/ and than replaces some name and id with name and ids and make the data to get fetched from DB instead of writing manually.

I am not sure why next drop down is not appearing :(

Comment: I don't any error.


@halfer , When I choose Class, It doesn't show next drop down menu.

Comment: @halfer You can see result here: http://i.snag.gy/jmCeX.jpg

Comment: @halfer, there isn't problem with the browser, every script with jQuery and Javascript is working fine.

Comment: There is a problem with this code which I am unable to figure out Sir

Comment: Sir Can you please check my jQuery and PHP Code and check where exactly the problem is ?

PHP is fetching data and showing in drop down when I don't use jQuery.

Comment: The Code : http://codebin.org/view/0b6d0cbe
The jQuery Code : http://codebin.org/view/32c5361b

Comment: I've looked at it already, and unless I were to recreate your environment, it is probably not possible to say what is wrong with it. You either need to do some debugging of your JavaScript, or put it live so people can see if there is something in the console that you have missed. (I didn't see your last four messages, since you did not address me by @handle).

Comment: (I have summarised a few of my comments above in an answer, and then deleted the comments, for tidiness. I imagine this question will close, as it is not a reproducible problem, but in the meantime do try my suggestions in the answer).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try some debugging in your JavaScript? Put temporary `alert()` statements in, thus:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert(1);

    $('#ChoosedClassID').on('change', function() {         
        alert(2);

        $('tr.Department_Options').hide();
        $('#tr_' + $(this).val() ).show();

    });

});
```

Do you get "1" on page load and "2" on the control change event? That's the first thing you need to do. If you do, you could perhaps move onto looking at `$(this).val()` to see what value that resolves to.

As I outlined in the comments, it is worth checking your browser's console, in case any JavaScript errors pop up. Also, check your network panel to ensure your external JavaScript resources (jQuery in particular) are loaded correctly.

Comment: Code : codebin.org/view/0b6d0cbe The jQuery Code : codebin.org/view/32c5361b

Comment: Let us know how you get on with debugging, @TrueCode.